# How to pass a list of COleDateTime objects as a SAFEARRAY*

Tags: c#, c++, datetime, mfc, safearray

This is my method definition:

```
IMSAToolsLibraryInterface : IUnknown
{
    //
    // Raw methods provided by interface
    //

      virtual HRESULT __stdcall SetPathXML (
        /*[in]*/ BSTR strPathXML,
        /*[out]*/ __int64 * iResult ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall SavePublisherData (
        /*[out]*/ __int64 * iResult ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall ReadPublisherData (
        /*[out]*/ __int64 * iResult ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall Test ( ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall AddPublisher (
        /*[in]*/ BSTR strName,
        /*[in]*/ BSTR strNotes,
        /*[in]*/ enum Gender eGender,
        /*[in]*/ enum Appointed eAppointedAs,
        /*[in]*/ enum Serving eServingAs,
        /*[in]*/ VARIANT_BOOL bUseForDemonstrations,
        /*[in]*/ VARIANT_BOOL bAvailableMidweek,
        /*[in]*/ VARIANT_BOOL bAvailableWeekend,
        /*[in]*/ SAFEARRAY * listDatesNotAvailable ) = 0;
};
```

It now has a new last parameter which is actually an array of DateTime objects in the C# DLL method. I have read up a bit on this subject and it seems that from `MFC` I need to use `COleSafeArray` to create a safe array of suitable entries.

It is confusing me.  I basically want to be able to pass a list of `COleDateTime` values as this `SAFEARRAY*` parameter and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You might want to use the C++ tag for this; the relation to C# is tangential at best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
COleSafeArray arr;
arr.CreateOneDim(VT_DATE, num_elements);

DATE* data;
arr.AccessData((void**)&data);
data[0] = my_date;
// Assign other elements as needed
arr.UnaccessData();

my_itf_pointer->AddPublisher(..., arr.parray);
```

Comment: Thanks. So if `my_date` a cast of a COleDateTime variable?

Comment: `COleDateTime` provides `operator DATE()`. An implicit cast should just work.